# SQLAlchemy core - how to make a ResultProxy case-insensitive wrt Schema column names?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, database-schema

When using SQL Alchemy core, how to I avoid errors from column name changes between backend databases?  I don't control the backends and I don't need to write to them, I just want to select data and look at the values.

Say you have `create table foo(bar int)`.  Or something similar.  In SQL Server it will be `create table FOO(BAR int)`

Execute `select * from FOO` and this will work in fine in Oracle, Postgres and MS Sqlserver.

However, Postgres and Oracle will return sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy instances where I can `print(row.bar)`.

While SQL Server will return the exact same data, using the exact same query but I have to use `print(row.BAR)`.

Now, each RowProxy in a result list uses a shared attribute, `_keymap` that maps fieldnames to location in the `_row` attribute which carries the data returned by the query for that database row.

So, given a _keymap `{u'bar': (None, None, 0)}`, which says that tuple position 0 holds **bar**, I could (and have done this) change to `{u'bar': (None, None, 0),u'BAR': (None, None, 0)}`.

Given that I could then `print(row.bar)` or `print(row.BAR)` without wondering whether the backend databases stores `bar` or `BAR`.

But, abstracting column upper/lower schema names seems a fairly common issue when using SQL Alchemy against multiple database engines, something it seems very competent at doing in general.

Did I miss something? Isn't there a built-in way?

This is SQL Alchemy using raw sql, i.e. my app builds the queries as plain sql.  I can't use the ORM, that's totally out of scope.  I also can't tweak the database backends' configurations to use upper or lower names - I don't control them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
create_engine(..., case_sensitive=False)
```

The [`case_sensitive`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.case_sensitive) parameter defaults to True. If set to False, result columns match case-insensitively.

```
In [15]: engine = create_engine('sqlite://', case_sensitive=False)

In [16]: metadata = MetaData()

In [17]: metadata.bind = engine

In [18]: tbl = Table('foo', metadata, Column('BAR', Text))

In [19]: metadata.create_all()

In [22]: engine.execute(tbl.insert().values([('asdf',), ('qwer',)]))
Out[22]: <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy at 0x7f03b4ba6b00>

In [23]: row = engine.execute(tbl.select()).fetchone()

In [24]: row
Out[24]: ('asdf',)

In [25]: row.BAR
Out[25]: 'asdf'

In [26]: row.BaR
Out[26]: 'asdf'

In [27]: row.bar
Out[27]: 'asdf'
```

Comment: I should have remembered to check *create_engine* options, that's where this type of stuff belongs.  My regression tests show it working and in any case, the basic usage I was asking about works just fine with your recommendation.  Txs!

Comment: Is this still working @Ilja Everilä ?`case_sensitive` seems to be deprecated -> https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.case_sensitive

Comment: It looks like it is on its way out, so applications should work towards handling names case sensitively. Of course that can be a challenge, if trying to make the same code work with multiple DBMS. Will have to revisit this at some point.